# docker containers are down in same time, and restart fail with error of write max to pids.max, how can i find the problem?

Tags: docker, restart

The ssh disconnected when i using a container,  and then i find all containers were dead.

I want to restart my container by

> docker restart mysql2

but fail with error

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused "process_linux.go:396: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \"failed to write max to pids.max: write /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/docker/3e8d10946219b7ba3a2259f8f21222c978dc51fade62fd882f02d191e24c8cb5/pids.max: invalid argument\""": unknown Error: failed to start containers: mysql2

Then i tried to restart docker and restart linux, both not work.

Is there any way to troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1):

i resolved this problem, the step:

1. docker update --pids-limit 40000 mysql2
2. docker restart mysql2

by reset the pids limit of docker, i can restart my container now.